# Is there a way I can skip tracing through the code in third party jars in eclipse debug mode

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I want to avoid getting into the details of code in the third party jar when I am in debug mode in eclipse.

Currently I am using Eclipse luna. I am tracing through a web application which makes use of play framework and I don't want to get into the play framework specific code and concentrate just of the written code by me.

How can I achieve this in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Window->Preferences` search for `Java` in the panel then go to `Debug` and select `Step Filtering` inside.

Check `Use Step Filters` and select the packages that you want to be excluded, more details on how to use this option [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/step-filtering-skip-certain).